# Swift date conversion for islamic calendar is wrong in specific timezone

Tags: swift, date, timezone, foundation

The Islamic calendar is updating ongoing (with the moon phase). For example **Ramadan** could have 1 less or more days. But it can't be predicted and it turns out at the end of the month itself. So the following code will not work correctly some times:

```
func islamicDate(of formattedDate: String) -> String {
    let timezone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "IRST")!

    // Get the date
    var inputCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .persian)
    inputCalendar.timeZone = timezone

    let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
    inputFormatter.calendar = inputCalendar
    inputFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
    inputFormatter.timeZone = timezone

    let date = inputFormatter.date(from: formattedDate)!

    // Convert the date
    var outputCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .islamic)
    outputCalendar.timeZone = timezone

    let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
    outputFormatter.calendar = outputCalendar
    outputFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM"
    outputCalendar.timeZone = timezone
    let outputFormattedDate = outputFormatter.string(from: date)

    return outputFormattedDate
}
```

for example, giving `1399/06/04` will result in:

> 06 Muharram

but expected to be

> 05 Muharram

Although it's correct in the other timezones, it's incorrect in the `IRST`. How is this can be sync with the current time adjastment of the timezone?

Comment: In what other timezone is it correct? I tried UTC and it's still wrong. It seems to me that this is, as you said, just impossible to predict

Comment: Okay, I understand that 1399 is A.H., but what I do not understand is: how is the length of Ramadan determined? I suspect there is some scripture-based criteria, but I'm not aware how can we find that.

Comment: @Sweeper that is the question. in Asia/Tehran (IRST) should be `05 Muharram` but it returns `06 Muharram`. And this caused **one day offset** for all the following dates.

Comment: @LajosArpad right. But shouldn't it get updated after detecting the change in some sort of timeserver? I thought Apple is very precise about the time. Even in nanoseconds, but seems like **a full (logical) day** does not matter here ‍♂️

Comment: So you mean in other timezones the correct date is `06 Muharram`, but in IRST it should be `05 Muharram`? If so, my question is why does the timezone matter? Isn't this a date problem? Unless there is DST transition on that day in IRST, of course...

Comment: If IRST is incorrect, but there is a correct timezone, then you may want to check the logical date in the other timezone and apply that for IRST.

Comment: @Sweeper I know its strange but its correct. Since the date came from the moon phase and sometimes moon orientation speed, the earth spinning, or other stuff mixed together in a way that in some place of earth, **the date setters!** see the thin moon of the next month or not. So it is how it gets incorrect in some timezone. But maybe I missed another setup to make it work.

Comment: @LajosArpad I am adding +1 or -1 or ∓0 manually. But since it's a known issue, I wonder if Apple has a solution for this.